# getStaticPaths not creating paths on production

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to connect WordPress and next.js and everything works ok on dev but I have one issue with the production version.

I have a page that shows all posts and after adding a new post in WP I can see this newly added post but when I'm trying to open the link I'm getting 404. I'm sure that this problem is caused by **getStaticPaths**.

That's how my slug page looks like

```
import {getAllPost, getPostBySlug} from "../../lib/api";

const PostPage = ({post}) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: post.content}}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps = async (ctx) => {

    const {slug} = ctx.params
    const post = await getPostBySlug(slug)

    return {
        props: {
            post
        },
        revalidate: 10
    }
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const posts = await getAllPost()

    const paths = posts.map(post => ({
        params: {slug: post.slug}
    }))

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

export default PostPage
```

The **getAllPost()** function in **getStaticPaths()** returns array of objects which contains post title and slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `fallback: false` in your static paths which means that only paths (in your case posts) available during build time can be statically generated. So no other post page will be ever shown.

To be able to show newly added post after you deploy your project use `fallback: true`.

Comment: thanks, some progress but now i have error ``` Cannot read property 'title' of undefined```

Comment: How does your `slug` param look like in getStaticProps during this error? And what is resukt of getSlugByPost then?

Comment: [Here are some](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths#fallback-false) relevant pages of the [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths#when-does-getstaticpaths-run) for this issue and solution